# Onenote notebook, sections and page IDs permanent?

Tags: onenote, onenote-api

I'm using the API here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/onenote-get-content#resource-paths-for-get-requests to get and write information to pages.

I was wondering if anybody knows whether the IDs retrieved through the API changes. I found this [Converting between OneNote Ids for internal vs HTML links?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20960183/converting-between-onenote-ids-for-internal-vs-html-links), which says that the runtime IDs change. But I tried a few calls and doesn't seem to change, so I'm very confused.

I'm wondering if there is a key like reference for Onenote objects, as like a google sheet where each sheet has a unique key and that never changes. I'm looking for an anchor like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Omer's answer in the thread linked is correct.